# Why is python asking me to install a package every time I re-run the ipynb notebook?

Tags: python-3.6, google-colaboratory

I am using google colaboratory with ipynb (Python 3.6.7), and every time I run the script and import a module [Scanpy python toolkit](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) it says I don't have it so I have to install it again, which take a few minutes.

There is a similar question here:

[How to prevent 'pip install …' running every time I run the whole notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481291/how-to-prevent-pip-install-running-every-time-i-run-the-whole-notebook)

The answer there is not satisfactory because scanpy would be installed every time I am running the script, which takes some minutes and that's undesired.

The way I installed scanpy is:

`!pip3 install scanpy[louvain]`

If I run the script again and try to import scanpy by doing:

`import scanpy as sc`

I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c75a4ac677d6> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 1 import scanpy as sc
      4 
      5 sc.settings.verbosity = 3 # verbosity: errors(0), warnings(1), info(2), hints(3)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scanpy'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I have to install it again, which is time consuming and should not happen, since other already installed packages (e.g. pandas, numpy, etc.) do not show this problem.

My question is:

**How can I install scanpy permanently?**

I should be able to import scanpy anytime without having to install it again, and again...

Comment: Can you share a notebook showing the install command you are using? `pip install scanpy` takes roughly 5 seconds for me in Colab.

Comment: The install command I am using is in the question, but here it is again: `!pip install scanpy[louvain]`

Comment: It took 6 minutes to install. @BobSmith here is the notebook:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13TKfg6F9yb4N80Sfz3fx7x_SUK0WHEGB?authuser=1#scrollTo=wMbQcJcBe-Uh

Comment: Please share the notebook. It seems to be private right now.

Comment: @BobSmith here it is: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13TKfg6F9yb4N80Sfz3fx7x_SUK0WHEGB

Comment: Thanks. I see the difference: I had tried `!pip install scanpy`, which is much faster.

Comment: @BobSmith, yeah, but for the analyses I am using adding the Louvain graph-clustering method, so I need to install it with the louvain package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the second point of this [3 Essential Google Colaboratory Tips & Tricks](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/essential-google-colaboratory-tips-tricks.html):

*Currently, **software installations within Google Colaboratory are not persistent, in that you must reinstall libraries every time you (re-)connect to an instance**. Since Colab has numerous useful common libraries installed by default, this is less of an issue than it may seem, and installing those libraries which are not pre-installed are easily added in one of a few different ways.*

This seems to be the reason why I have to re-install each time scanpy, as it is not a default package of Colaboratory.